# Set thickness of a line between table rows

Tags: css, css-tables

How can I change the thickness of a line between the two table rows
eg:

[image: Imgur]

(the one highlighted).

This is how my code looks like at the moment:

```css
i {
  cursor: pointer;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
}

th {
  white-space: pre-wrap;
  font-size: 25px;
  color: goldenrod;
}

p {
  font-family: 'BioRhyme', serif;
  font-size: 35px;
}
```

```html
<table class="table table-hover table-borderless">
  <thead class="thead-dark">
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>IP</th>
      <th>Port</th>
      <th>Ping</th>
      <th>Players</th>
    </tr>

  </thead>
  <tbody id="table">
    <tr>
      <th>Hexah's Test</th>
      <th>0.0.0.0</th>
      <th>27015</th>
      <th>koala</th>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <th>Hexah's Test</th>
      <th>0.0.0.0</th>
      <th>27015</th>
      <th>koala</th>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

I'm using [Bootstrap Material Design v4](https://fezvrasta.github.io/bootstrap-material-design/)

Thanks!

Comment: Simply increase the `border-width` unless the underline is an image.

Comment: @ManojKumar I've been trying to do that but it didn't work neither in the table nor in the table row

Comment: But people here can't help you without seeing your code or the output in the image :( Hence the down votes.

Comment: Please create a [MCVE] within your question.

Comment: I've added my code, I should be ok now... I hope

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can increase the border width between items in a table by using this in your CSS file:

```
td {
  border-bottom: 5px solid black;
  border-top: 5px solid black;
}
```

You can change the `color`, `thickness`, and the `style` of the border using those 3 values. You can, of course, add these properties to the `th` and `table` as well, changing the `border` style to other sides:

- `border`
- `border-right`
- `border-left`

Learn more about CSS tables [here](https://www.w3schools.com/Css/css_table.asp).